# JS - Can I get the next open div element - Not the sibling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible using just JS (or possibly with jQuery) to get the next `open` html element?

In the snippet below, if I click on any `div` it'll give me the `id` of that div. I want it to get the *next* open element id, so e.g.

if I click on `page123` it should give me `123efter`
if I click on `123efter` it should give me `13`

I don't want the next sibling within the encapsulating `div`, which is all I've managed to do so far!

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
console.log(event.target.id);
}
);
```

```css
.efter{
min-height:20px;
}
.efter:hover{
background-color:beige;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="1">
    home
    <div id="1efter" class="efter"></div>
    <div id="11">
      page11
      <div id="11efter" class="efter"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="12">
      page12
      <div id="12efter" class="efter"></div>
      <div id="121">
        page121
        <div id="121efter" class="efter"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="122">
        page122
        <div id="122efter" class="efter"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="123">
        page123
        <div id="123efter" class="efter"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="13">
      page13
      <div id="13efter" class="efter"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first create a flat array `divs` with all existing div `id`s. In the click event handler I then look up the clicked element's successor `id`.

```js
const divs=[...document.body.querySelectorAll("div")].map(d=>d.id);
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
console.log(divs[divs.indexOf(event.target.id)+1]);
}
);
```

```css
.efter{
min-height:20px;
}
.efter:hover{
background-color:beige;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="1">
    home
    <div id="1efter" class="efter"></div>
    <div id="11">
      page11
      <div id="11efter" class="efter"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="12">
      page12
      <div id="12efter" class="efter"></div>
      <div id="121">
        page121
        <div id="121efter" class="efter"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="122">
        page122
        <div id="122efter" class="efter"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="123">
        page123
        <div id="123efter" class="efter"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="13">
      page13
      <div id="13efter" class="efter"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! I had discovered something similar actually but this works perfectly so accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, and as tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), you can use jquery's `collection.index(element)` overload to get the index within a collection.

As a one liner:

```
console.log($("div").eq($("div").index(this) + 1))
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$("div").click(function(evt) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
   
   // Get once so it's not run multiple times
   var divs = $("div");
   var idx = divs.index(this);
   var result = divs.eq(idx+1)
   
   // do something to demo
   console.log(idx, result.attr("id"));
   $(".active").removeClass("active");
   result.addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.efter{
min-height:20px;
}
.efter:hover{
background-color:beige;
}
.active { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="1">
    home
    <div id="1efter" class="efter"></div>
    <div id="11">
      page11
      <div id="11efter" class="efter"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="12">
      page12
      <div id="12efter" class="efter"></div>
      <div id="121">
        page121
        <div id="121efter" class="efter"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="122">
        page122
        <div id="122efter" class="efter"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="123">
        page123
        <div id="123efter" class="efter"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="13">
      page13
      <div id="13efter" class="efter"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```